# public/packages empty after publishing assets

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, package, assets

I have installed a package (ipunkt/laravel-notify) that has assets that need to be published to the public folder. I have tried

```
 php artisan asset:publish ipunkt/laravel-notify
```

and I get the message

```
 Assets published for package: ipunkt\laravel-notify
```

however public/packages remains empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this (version 1.0.0) and I'm seeing the published assets correctly. Can you publish assets for other packages?

Comment: This is the first one I tried, what's a good one to try?

Comment: Hmm, that makes me think it won't work for any package, but to be sure, try with https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar.

Comment: yeh it says both were published but the contents of public haven't changed

Comment: Does PHP have write permissions to the public folder?

Comment: var_dump(is_writable("../public")); and var_dump(is_writable("../public/packages")); both return true :/

Comment: answered the question, I can't believe laravel comes with the public directory setup incorrectly out the box. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Had to change

```
 'public' => __DIR__.'/../..'
```

to

```
 'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'
```

in bootstrap/paths.php

Comment: It does come out of the box with the path configured correctly: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/paths.php.